# How do I replace Kotlin Synthetics in an Adapter?

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I've been following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxBhn0j8kws&list=PL7NYbSE8uaBDFULNYVBV8kCyaG6OyMeaq&index=7) for setting up an Instagram clone app, however it uses Kotlin Synthetics which are now deprecated.

I've been trying to modify it to use viewFindByID but it doesn't seem compatible with the viewHolder/Recycler view being used.

How to replace Kotlin Synthetics in this case?

**PostAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.dndgroupfinder

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.format.DateUtils
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.dndgroupfinder.models.Post

private const val TAG = "post_item"

class PostAdapter (val context: Context, val posts: List<Post>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }
    
    override fun getItemCount() = posts.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(posts[position])

    }

    inner class  ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(post: Post) {
            textViewUsername = view.findViewByID(R.id.textViewUsername)
            itemView.textViewUsername.text =post.user?.username
            itemView.textViewDescription.text = post.description
            Glide.with(context).load(post.imageUrl).into(itemView.imageViewPostImage)
            itemView.textViewPostTime.text = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(post.creationTimeMs)
        }
    }
}
```

**post_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:text="Aidan" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPostTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="5 days ago" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPostImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        tools:text="Here we go!!!" />
    
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**PostFeedActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.dndgroupfinder

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.dndgroupfinder.models.Post
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query

private const val TAG = "PostFeedActivity"
class PostFeedActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var firestoreDatabase: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var posts: MutableList<Post>
    private lateinit var adapter: PostAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.postfeed_activity)

        //Layout file for one post -Done
        //create data source -Done
        posts = mutableListOf()
        //create adapter
        adapter = PostAdapter(this, posts)
        //bind adapter and layout manager to RV

        val recviewposts = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recviewposts)
        recviewposts.adapter = adapter
        recviewposts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


        firestoreDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val postFeedReference = firestoreDatabase
            .collection("posts")
            .limit(20)
            .orderBy("creation_time_ms", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

        postFeedReference.addSnapshotListener{snapshot, exception ->
            if (exception != null || snapshot == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception when querying posts", exception)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            val postList = snapshot.toObjects(Post::class.java)
            posts.clear()
            posts.addAll(postList)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            for (post in postList) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Post $post")
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.postfeed_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menuToProfile) {
            val intent = Intent(this, UserProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` will always work - that's the old school way of finding a View on a layout hierarchy, and that's what things like synthetics were using under the hood.

First, it's **Id** not **ID** so make sure you're using the correct function name:

```
// wrong
val textViewUsername = view.findViewByID(R.id.textViewUsername)
// right
val textViewUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername)
```

I'm using `val` because you're creating a variable with a reference to that view you just looked up. Synthetics used an automagical *"you didn't declare a variable but there's sorta one there anyway"* thing which confuses a lot of people - so you need to explicitly create and assign those variables.

Which means you can't do this:

```
itemView.textViewUsername.text = post.user?.username
```

`itemView` doesn't actually have a variable called `textViewUsername`, so you can't access the view like that. A typical way to do it is when you create the `ViewHolder`, you do all your lookups to get references to the views during initialisation:

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    // declare and look up all your view references at construction time
    val username = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewUsername)
    ...
}
```

and *now* you can access them easily in your `bind` function:

```
fun bind(post: Post) {
    // referencing the 'username' variable we defined, which points to the TextView
    username.text = post.user?.username
```

---

If you use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) it works in a very similar way to synthetics - instead, it generates a binding object which has all your view references automatically added, so you don't need to create the variables yourself. And that's the recommended approach to migrate away from synthetics:

```
// Pass in the binding object instead, which has all your named view references.
// Make it a property (val) so you can access it later, and pass the whole view
// hierarchy (binding.root) to the super constructor
inner class  ViewHolder(val binding: PostItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(post: Post) {
        // Now you can just reference views through your binding object
        // It's pretty much the same code as before, with 'binding' instead of 'itemView'
        binding.textViewUsername.text = post.user?.username
        binding.textViewDescription.text = post.description
        ...
    }
}

// when creating a ViewHolder, create the binding object (using inflate creates
// the views as well as binding the references to them)
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val binding = PostItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```